# when I type my react js component it is doing well but when i reload the browser it gives me error Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx

this is App js
import React from "react"

```html
import React from "react"

import {Cards , Chart , CountryPicker} from "./Components"
import styles from "./App.module.css"
import {fetchData} from "./api"

class App extends React.Component{
    state = {
        data : {},
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        const fetchedData = await fetchData()
        this.setState({data : fetchedData})
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <Cards data={this.state.data}/>
                <CountryPicker />
                <Chart />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

'''
and this is Card component

```
import React from "react"
import {Card, CardContent, Typography, Grid} from '@material-ui/core'
import styles from "./Cards.module.css"
import CountUp from "react-countup"

const Cards = (props) => {
   console.log(props)
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <Grid container spacing={3} justify="center">
            <Grid item component={Card}>
               <CardContent>
                <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>Infected</Typography>
                <Typography variant="h5"><CountUp start={0} end={props.data.confirmed.value} separator="," duration={2} /></Typography>
                <Typography color="textSecondary">{new Date(props.data.lastUpdate).toDateString()}</Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2">Number of Active cases of Covid-19</Typography>
               </CardContent>
            </Grid> 
            <Grid item component={Card}>
               <CardContent>
                <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>Recovered</Typography>
                <Typography variant="h5"><CountUp start={0} end={props.data.recovered.value} separator="," duration={2} /></Typography>
                <Typography color="textSecondary">{new Date(props.data.lastUpdate).toDateString()}</Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2">Number of Recoveries from Covid-19</Typography>
               </CardContent>
            </Grid> 
            <Grid item component={Card}>
               <CardContent>
                <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>Deaths</Typography>
                <Typography variant="h5"><CountUp start={0} end={props.data.deaths.value} separator="," duration={2} /></Typography>
                <Typography color="textSecondary">{new Date(props.data.lastUpdate).toDateString()}</Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2">Number of Deaths caused by Covid-19</Typography>
               </CardContent>
            </Grid> 
        </Grid>
      </div>
    )
}

export default Cards
```

'''

Comment: 1) you need to have default props for your top level keys of `props.data` or 2) show a loader in your card component until the props are passed thru.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to check if you have data in your object.

So try something like below:-

```
// add optional chaining for below 
props.data.confirmed.value => props.data.confirmed?.value
props.data.recovered.value => props.data.recovered?.value
props.data.deaths.value => props.data.deaths?.value
```

Comment: it worked , it stopped giving me the error but 
it is not showing me the data I'm trying to get 
I'm only getting this error when i use CountUp , do you think there is a problem with it?

Comment: I am sorry i did not understand `CountUp` part. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: sorry for the late replay , so in the tutorial video I'm watching , he put <CountUp /> at  the number im getting , so if im getting like "150" from the api , the countUp will make it show up with an effect , like its going from 0 to 150 in a specific duration , it's a cool effect though when im putting it , im getting that error and when i delete it and get the number from the api without it , its all good
its in this link : 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countup

Answer (score 0):

Because the initial state is undefined. Put your code inside an if statement so it doesn't give an error.

```
<div className={styles.container}>
  if(this.state) {
    <Cards data={this.state.data}/>
  } else {
    <p>Loading data...</p>
  }
  <CountryPicker />
  <Chart />
</div>
```

Comment: try something like if(this.state !== undefined && this.state !== null)